# Unity Console not showing result and Object disappears on running

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I installed unity hub and added editor ''Unity 2021.1.7f1''.
Now i wrote a simple script in Visual studio Code (VSC shows no error in it), the script is to just write something in the Console, here it is[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvZqg.jpg)

I attached the script to an empty object[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GqFU.jpg)

Now on running the console shows nothing[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef9Iv.png)
Why is this happening?

Now i created a 2D square object and added a script to it that i copied from the tutorial i was learning from, VSC shows no error in it as well. Here it is[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COvHJ.jpg)

I attached this script to the square[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQoCh.jpg)

When i press the run the square disappears from the assets.[here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jUaE.png)

I am new so please forgive if i made some technical error. I need help with these two problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is caused by a typo in your script, you typed `start()` instead of `Start()` (Notice the capital `S`, Unity Event functions are case sensitive.)

For the second issue, it looks you you added the square object while in play mode which doesn't persist changes. You need to make sure you only make changes in Edit mode if you want them to be persisted.